# Methods to set content view in Jetpack Compose UI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I had three question

1. There is `setViewContent` which accept `composable` function as input parameter similar to
   `setContent`. So, what is a difference between `setViewContent` and `setContent` and its use-cases. You can able to see `setViewContent` in `androidx.compose` package.
2. `setContent` and `setViewContent` both return `CompositionContext?`. So, how and for what, we will use `CompositionContent`.
3. Is there any way to integrate existing `layout.xml` with new `compose ui` in **same** activity or fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my comments and my understanding:

1. `setContent` will make the composable passed as parameter as the root component of your activity/fragment. On the other hand, `setViewContent` will add a `FrameLayout` as root element of your activity/fragment which allow you to add another views on it.
2. Both methods return a `Composition` object, which afaik, it's used just to display the content via `setContent` and clear the hierarchy that was created from the composition via `dispose`.
3. Yes, in `dev14` you can use `AndroidView` like this:

```
AndroidView(resId = R.layout.my_layout) { view ->
    val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    ...    
}
```

Comment: This is not Compose

Comment: Yes, it is my friend :) `AndroidView` is a composable function to add a `View` into another composable function.